# @HostBinding disabling class from child component Angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an angular app which has user login and logout. I am showing up a welcome page as the home page before a user logs in. I want to enable a background image only on the welcome page. Once the user logs in, the background image must disappear. When the user logs out, he will be redirected to welcome page which must show up the background image again.

I have tried using @HostBinding in the app.component.ts by renaming the selector to 'body'.

```
app.component.ts

import {Component, HostBinding, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {InputMask} from "primeng/primeng";

@Component({
  selector: 'body',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  path = '../assets/img/AvayaHome.jpg';
  title = 'app';
  toggleClass = true;
  @HostBinding('class.bodyClass') isWelcomePage = this.toggleClass;
}
```

Here is my CSS.

```
app.component.css

.bodyClass  {
    background-image: url("../assets/img/AvayaHome.jpg");
}
```

Here is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title> Something </title>
</head>
<body class="bodyClass">

    <app-welcome-page></app-welcome-page>

</body>
</html>
```

I am enabling the css style for bodyClass by assigning toggleClass as true. Once the user logs in, I am changing the value of toggleClass (which is in the app.component.ts) from the child component.

Here is my login.component.ts

```
onLogin() {
    console.log('onLogin() invoked:', this._email, ':' , this.password);
    if (this._email == null || this.password == null) {
      this.errorMessage = 'All fields are required';
      return;
    }
    this.errorMessage = null;
    this.loginservice.authenticate(this._email, this.password);
    this.appComponent.toggleClass = true;
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
  }
```

The value of the toggleClass changes when the user logs in to FALSE. But I am still seeing the background image. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, let's take a look at this code:

```
var toggleClass = false;
var isWelcomePage = toggleClass;

console.log(isWelcomePage); // prints true
```

Cool, all works as expected.

Ten seconds later....

Some user logins:

```
toggleClass = true;

console.log(isWelcomePage); // prints false
```

Why it has not changed???

If you open any documentation or any book about javascript you can read one main rule:

**Primitives are always immutable.**

When we assign `toggleClass` variable to `isWelcomePage` variable using =, we **copy the value** to the new variable because primitives are copied by value.

**Solution 1:**

Change `isWelcomePage` property directly

```
onLogin() {
  ...
  this.appComponent.isWelcomePage = true;
  ...
}
```

**Solution 2**

Define getter

```
@HostBinding('class.bodyClass')
get isWelcomePage() {
  return this.toggleClass;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically display and hide a background you should use a conditional class with `ngClass`

You can read more about it here [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

In your case it would be

```
<div [ngClass]="{'bodyClass': isWelcomePage}">    
    ...
</div>
```

Then `bodyClass` css class will only apply **IF** `isWelcomePage` is `true`, if it's `false` it won't apply and the image won't show.

Edit:

As requested, a working example: [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/uZOlI0exkUlIQyPHDnnV)

Comment: NgClass works for any tag but it must be inside your component.

Comment: You should have a _root_ component which fakes the body tag (spans the entire website) if you want to do things like that.

Comment: I did the same as you can see my code above. but that still doesn't work. If I misunderstood, can you provide a code sample here. Thanks!

Comment: You used `@HostBinding` which doesn't work like that ... I've provided a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function with if and else;

```
if (user is login) {
  document.body.classList.add('bodyClass');
} else {
  document.body.classList.remove('bodyClass');
}
```

Than call that function when ever you need, `logIn` `logOut` etc

Answer (score -1):

Hostbinding only binds stuff to host tag, in your case  tag.

So if you want to manipulate the body tag, you have to do it using plan javascript from your component or also create a component in the body.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'body',
  template: `<child></child>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  @HostBinding('class') public cssClass = 'class1';
}
```